# How to Create an Opinion System between Characters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let us say that I have a Scriptable Object 'Characters' and I create three Characters of that Scriptable Object. Now I want three of the characters to have a opinion (int value) about the other two characters. Like Character 1 has 30 opinion about Character 2 and Character 1 has -30 opinion about Character 2.

The easy way I think is to create two ints in the Characters Scriptable Object but if I had 1000 Characters, do I have to create 1000 ints. Any idea on how to create this system?

Comment: You need a container, a dictionary might do well in this case, so a dictionary that links a 'Character' to an int.

E.g Character1.opinions(character2) and the value would be your opinion rating. You then just need a startup script to dynamically fill these dictionaries for every character at the start

Comment: I am a 14 year old and I am a less than a complete beginner in UNITY. Can you show me the code to do so?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary might be a good place to start.

Comment: If you have 1000 characters then you will have to store `n * (n - 1) = 999000` opinions where `n` is the number of characters. I.e., every character (`n`) has an opinion for all the other (`n - 1`) characters.

Comment: Can I set any Object in the dictionary. Like a Character Class. Something like IDictionary<Character, int> dict = new Dictionary<Character, int>();

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I could not get you. But I prefer using the Dictionary if it works for any class.

Comment: It depends. If the number of characters is constant, you can simply use a matrix (2d array).

Comment: I do not think that the no. of characters will be constant. I like to create Alternate History Strategy Games where Characters will spawn regularly. Something like Europa Universalis IV.

Comment: If you have 3 characters (`n = 3`), then every of these 3 has an opinion on 2 others (`n - 1`), i.e., you have to store `n * (n-1) = 3 * 2 = 6 opinions`. This number grows in a quadratic way with the number of characters.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes And then use an array to store these 6 opinions. That's all right. But what if n increases by one mid-game, then how will I set the opinions using an array for the rest of the characters. Maybe I should create a basic character system in Unity and then re-edit this question. Will that work?

Comment: I said *"If the number of characters is constant, ..."*. If it is not, then a dictionary, as you suggested, it is probably the best.

Comment: All right, thanks. Then Dictionary is the way to go I guess

Comment: Tbh, there are so many things to this it would really depend on exactly what and how you are using it for.  My questions if I was the developer making this system would be:  1.  Does this information need to be stored on a character for every character in the game?  2.  Will every character meet all the other characters in the game?  3.  Will there ever be a time when all character are present in the same scene at the same time? 4.  How often is this system used?  Does it affect actual gameplay elements such as if you are in combat, are they less likely to heal someone they dislike(AI related)

Comment: Odds are if this system is only used for dialogue and influences which response a character gives or gets, then I would create a system that can be stored and only load that information when it is absolutely needed and only with the character involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a brilliant Answer in Unity Answers for this Question. Check it out if you want to.

Here is how to do it:

1. Create a new class inheriting from ScriptableObject
2. In this class, declare a 2D array containing the opinions, and an array containing your characters
3. Make a custom inspector to display this grid

Character.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;

 [CreateAssetMenu()]
 public class Character : ScriptableObject
 {
     public string Name;
 }
```

OpinionsTable.cs

```
using UnityEngine;


 [CreateAssetMenu()]
 public class OpinionsTable : ScriptableObject
 {
     [SerializeField]
     private Character[] characters;

     [SerializeField]
     private int[] opinions;
     public int GetOpinion( Character character1, Character character2 )
     {
         for( int i = 0 ; i < characters.Length ; ++i )
         {
             if( character1 == characters[i] )
             {
                 for( int j = 0 ; j < characters.Length ; ++j )
                 {
                     if( character2 == characters[j] )
                         return opinions[i * characters.Length + j];;
                 }
                 Debug.LogError( "Character2 not found" );
             }
         }
         Debug.LogError( "Character1 not found" );
         return -1;
     }
     public void SetOpinion( Character character1, Character character2, int opinion )
     {
         for( int i = 0 ; i < characters.Length ; ++i )
         {
             if( character1 == characters[i] )
             {
                 for( int j = 0 ; j < characters.Length ; ++j )
                 {
                     if( character2 == characters[j] )
                     {
                         opinions[i * characters.Length + j] = opinion;
                         return ;
                     }
                 }
                 Debug.LogError( "Character2 not found" );
             }
         }
         Debug.LogError( "Character1 not found" );
     }
 }
```

**In a Folder Called 'Editor'**

OpinionsTableEditor.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEditor;

 [CustomEditor( typeof( OpinionsTable ) )]
 public class OpinionsTableEditor : Editor
 {
     const float opinionsLabelWidth = 50;
     const float opinionCellSize = 25;
     SerializedProperty characters;
     SerializedProperty opinions;
     int opinionsTableWidth = 0;
     Rect opinionsTableRect;

     void OnEnable()
     {
         // Retrieve the serialized properties
         characters = serializedObject.FindProperty( "characters" );
         opinions = serializedObject.FindProperty( "opinions" );
     }

     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
     {
         serializedObject.Update();

         // Check if the number of characters has been changed
         // If so, resize the opinions
         EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField( characters, true );
         if( EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() )
         {
             opinions.arraySize = characters.arraySize * characters.arraySize;
         }

         // Draw opinions if there is more than one character
         if ( opinions.arraySize > 1 )
             DrawOpinions( opinions, characters );
         else
             EditorGUILayout.LabelField( "Not enough characters to draw opinions matrix" );

         serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
     }

     private void DrawOpinions( SerializedProperty opinions, SerializedProperty characters )
     {
         int charactersCount = characters.arraySize;
         if ( Event.current.type == EventType.Layout )
             opinionsTableWidth = Mathf.FloorToInt( EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth );

         // Get the rect of the whole matric, labels included
         Rect rect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(opinionsTableWidth, opinionsTableWidth, EditorStyles.inspectorDefaultMargins);

         if ( opinionsTableWidth > 0 && Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint )
             opinionsTableRect = rect;

         // Draw matrix and labels only if the rect has been computed
         if( opinionsTableRect.width > 0 )
         {
             // Compute size of opinion cell
             float cellWidth     = Mathf.Min( (opinionsTableRect.width - opinionsLabelWidth) / charactersCount, opinionCellSize );
             Rect opinionCell    = new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth, opinionsTableRect.y + opinionsLabelWidth, cellWidth, cellWidth );
             Matrix4x4 guiMatrix = GUI.matrix;

             // Draw vertical labels
             for ( int i = 1 ; i <= charactersCount ; ++i )
             {
                 Rect verticalLabelRect = new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + i * opinionCell.width, opinionsTableRect.y, opinionsLabelWidth, opinionsLabelWidth );
                 Character character = characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i - 1 ).objectReferenceValue as Character;
                 EditorGUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot( 90f, new Vector2( verticalLabelRect.x, verticalLabelRect.y ) );
                 EditorGUI.LabelField( verticalLabelRect, character == null ? "???" : character.Name );
                 GUI.matrix = guiMatrix;
             }            

             // Draw matrix
             for ( int i = 0 ; i < charactersCount ; ++i )
             {
                 // Draw horizontal labels
                 SerializedProperty characterProperty = characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i );
                 Character character = characterProperty == null ? null : characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i ).objectReferenceValue as Character;
                 EditorGUI.LabelField( new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x, opinionCell.y, opinionsLabelWidth, opinionCell.height ), character == null ? "???" : character.Name ) ;

                 for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
                 {
                     opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
                     if ( j > i )
                     {
                         SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
                         opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
                     }
                     else // Put grey box because the matrix is symmetrical
                     {
                         EditorGUI.DrawRect( opinionCell, Color.grey );
                     }
                 }
                 opinionCell.y += cellWidth; 
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

[image]

**Note**

If you want to extend your code a bit further like Character A will have an Opinion of Character B. But Character B will also have an opinion about Character A. Then do the following changes in OpinionsTableEditor.cs

Change this

```
 for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
              {
                  opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
                  if ( j > i )
                  {
                      SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
                      opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
                  }
                  else // Put grey box because the matrix is symmetrical
                  {
                      EditorGUI.DrawRect( opinionCell, Color.grey );
                  }
              }
```

To This

```
 for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
              {
                  opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
                  SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
                  opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
              }
```